# how to use retry with backoff in correct way?

Tags: project-reactor

i was trying to do the delay retry with backoff , and i copy the  demo which is in [offical  retrywhen demo](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/index.html#faq.exponentialBackoff)   , however , as  run this case ,it seems  invalid

here is my code

```
AtomicInteger errorCount = new AtomicInteger();
Flux<String> flux =
        Flux.<String>error(new IllegalStateException("boom"))
                .doOnError(e -> {
                    errorCount.incrementAndGet();
                    System.out.println(e + " at " + LocalTime.now());
                })
                .retryWhen(Retry
                        .backoff(3, Duration.ofMillis(100))
                        .jitter(0d)
                        .doAfterRetry(rs -> System.out.println("retried at " + LocalTime.now() + ", attempt " + rs.totalRetries()))
                        .onRetryExhaustedThrow((spec, rs) -> rs.failure())
                );
flux.subscribe();
```

here is my demo log

```
2023-01-10 18:54:43.851 [main] DEBUG reactor.util.Loggers.debug-254 - Using Slf4j logging framework
java.lang.IllegalStateException: boom at 18:54:43.873

Process finished with exit code 0
```

apparently, above log is lack something about the `doAfterRetry` , and retry with backoff  did not take effect

here is my env

```
java version "1.8.0_281"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_281-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.281-b09, mixed mode)


reactor-core : 3.5.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you run this code but note that `subscribe` is not blocking and it could happen that you program exits before code finishes.

Better use `StepVerifier` to test the logic

```
@Test
void retryTest() {
    AtomicInteger errorCount = new AtomicInteger();
    Flux<String> flux = Flux.<String>error(new IllegalStateException("boom"))
            .doOnError(e -> {
                errorCount.incrementAndGet();
                System.out.println(e + " at " + LocalTime.now());
            })
            .retryWhen(Retry
                    .backoff(3, Duration.ofMillis(100))
                    .jitter(0d)
                    .doAfterRetry(rs -> System.out.println("retried at " + LocalTime.now() + ", attempt " + rs.totalRetries()))
                    .onRetryExhaustedThrow((spec, rs) -> rs.failure())
            );

    StepVerifier.create(flux)
            .expectError(IllegalStateException.class)
            .verify();

    assertEquals(4, errorCount.get());
}
```

Here is an output

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: boom at 10:08:27.830016
retried at 10:08:28.001982, attempt 0
java.lang.IllegalStateException: boom at 10:08:28.005457
retried at 10:08:28.207456, attempt 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: boom at 10:08:28.207713
retried at 10:08:28.610774, attempt 2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: boom at 10:08:28.611011
```

Comment: truely ,flux with  subscribe  happen the program exits
thanks for you help , via the case you provide  that reslove  my problem,